# Error in R using function rbind "names do not match previous names"

Tags: r, error-handling, compiler-errors, statistics

My R code looks this way (all needed libraries are added too):

```
  t_descriptive_g<- x %>% group_by(cntry) %>%
      summarise(mean_stflife=mean(stflife),
                stand.D_stflife = sd(stflife),
                mean_pray=mean(pray),
                stand.D_pray=sd(pray),
                N=n())
    t_descriptive_a<- x %>%
      summarise(mean_stflife=mean(stflife),
                stand.D_stflife = sd(stflife),
                mean_pray=mean(pray),
                stand.D_pray=sd(pray),
                N=n())
    t<- rbind(t_descriptive_g, cbind(group="Total", t_descriptive_a))
    kable(t)
```

By running this line:

```
t<- rbind(t_descriptive_g, cbind(group="Total", t_descriptive_a))
```

I got such an error:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

My data (first 19 rows): 
[image]

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your column name in `cbind` should be `cntry` which will match the column name in `t_descriptive_g`.

```
data <- rbind(t_descriptive_g, cbind(cntry="Total", t_descriptive_a))
```